# GIT - Problems when merging files

Tags: git, merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I am trying to merge two branches from two features of my project(master into branch XXX). But instead of throwing merge conflicts, git is removing some content(and even some files) because they don't exists in master.

Is that correct? I wasn't expecting to have this thing happen. I was prepared to fix the conflicts, not to have them deleted.

Comment: Need more information: which branch are you merging in which one? Where are your branches created from? Please provide a commit graph and the commands you're trying?

Answer (score 1):

It's correct. If on feature A you delete a file and then you merge it into master, file A will be deleted if it wasn't touched on master after branches diverged. If it had been *touched* on master, you would get a conflict.